# How to use Alias in Where clause?

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, ora-00904

I have this procedure:

```
 PROCEDURE P_LOAD_EXPIRED_ACCOUNT
  (
  pDayDiff IN NUMBER,
  ExpiredCur OUT MEGAGREEN_CUR
  )
  IS
  BEGIN
  OPEN ExpiredCur FOR
  SELECT 
  ACCOUNT_NAME, SERVICE_TYPE, 
      CASE 
      WHEN SERVICE_TYPE = 1 THEN ADD_MONTHS(ACTIVATED_DATE,3)
      WHEN SERVICE_TYPE = 2 THEN ADD_MONTHS(ACTIVATED_DATE,6)
      WHEN SERVICE_TYPE = 3 THEN ADD_MONTHS(ACTIVATED_DATE,12)        
       END 
       AS EXPIRED_DATE
  FROM SUBSCRIBERS
  WHERE (EXPIRED_DATE - CURRENT_DATE) < pDayDiff;
  END;
```

but SQL Developer generate this error:

Error(20,10): PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "EXPIRED_DATE": invalid identifier

I believe that PLSQL allows me to use Alias in Where clause, but is there something I forgot?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't reference the column alias in the WHERE clause - your options are:

- replicate the CASE statement in the WHERE clause
- use a subquery:

  ```
  PROCEDURE P_LOAD_EXPIRED_ACCOUNT(pDayDiff NUMBER,
                                   ExpiredCur OUT MEGAGREEN_CUR)
  IS
  BEGIN


     OPEN ExpiredCur FOR
     SELECT x.account_name,
            x.service_type, 
            x.expired_date
       FROM (SELECT s.account_name,
                    s.service_type, 
                    CASE 
                       WHEN s.service_type = 1 THEN ADD_MONTHS(ACTIVATED_DATE,3)
                       WHEN s.service_type = 2 THEN ADD_MONTHS(ACTIVATED_DATE,6)
                       WHEN s.service_type = 3 THEN ADD_MONTHS(ACTIVATED_DATE,12)        
                    END AS EXPIRED_DATE
               FROM SUBSCRIBERS s) x
      WHERE x.expired_date - CURRENT_DATE < pDayDiff;


  END;
  ```

  ### Oracle 9i+

  ```
  WITH summary AS (
    SELECT s.account_name,
           s.service_type, 
           CASE 
              WHEN s.service_type = 1 THEN ADD_MONTHS(ACTIVATED_DATE,3)
              WHEN s.service_type = 2 THEN ADD_MONTHS(ACTIVATED_DATE,6)
              WHEN s.service_type = 3 THEN ADD_MONTHS(ACTIVATED_DATE,12)        
           END AS EXPIRED_DATE
      FROM SUBSCRIBERS s)
     SELECT x.account_name,
            x.service_type, 
            x.expired_date
       FROM summary x
      WHERE x.expired_date - CURRENT_DATE < pDayDiff;
  ```