# Oracle Invalid Identifier Error

Tags: sql, oracle

I know this has been asked before but I've looked at other questions and my query still won't work. I have a table with MLB batting stats from last 100 years or so, I am trying to find the playerid, homeruns and percentage of that year's (2012) total homerun's hit that player's hrs make up.

query:

```
select playerid, hr, hr/sum(hr) over (partition by playerid, yearid)*100 p
from mlbbattingstats 
where yearid=2012 and p != 0
order by hr;
```

error:

> Error at line 3:
>   ORA-00904: "P": invalid identifier

I have tried multiple different aliases and gotten the same error. Any help in what I am doing wrong would be appreciated and sorry if this has been answered previously.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3852831/how-to-use-alias-in-where-clause

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't reference a column alias on the same query level (except for `order by`). You need to wrap the statement into a derived table:

```
select *
from (
  select playerid, hr, hr/sum(hr) over (partition by playerid, yearid)*100 p
  from mlbbattingstats 
  where yearid = 2012 
) 
where p <> 0
order by hr;
```

Comment: thanks, that makes sense but now I get the error on ERROR at line 6:
ORA-00904: "YEARID": invalid identifier

Comment: @user3587186: ah right. Copy and paste error, sorry. You can move the `yearid = 2012` into the derived table (what I did) or add the `yearid` to the select list and keep both where conditions together on the outer query (performance wise it won't matter for this simple query)

Answer (score 1):

If `p <> 0`, then `hr <> 0`.  So, your query would seem to be equivalent to:

```
select playerid, hr,
       hr/sum(hr) over (partition by playerid, yearid)*100 as p
from mlbbattingstats 
where yearid = 2012 and hr <> 0
order by hr;
```

Your original problem is that you cannot use a column alias defined in a `select` in the `where` clause as the same level.