# Reason alias works in ORDER BY but not in WHERE

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I understand that [I can't reference an alias in the WHERE clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3852831/how-to-use-alias-in-where-clause), but why is that? Is it interpreted differently?

Something like this generates an error:

```
declare @myTable table 
(
    num numeric(5,2),
    den numeric(5,2)
)
insert into @mytable 
select 1, 2
union
select 1, 3
union
select 2, 3
union
select 2, 4
union
select 2, 5
union
select null, 1

select num/den as 'calc' from @myTable
where calc is not null
order by calc
```

But this returns rows:

```
declare @myTable table 
(
    num numeric(5,2),
    den numeric(5,2)
)
insert into @mytable 
select 1, 2
union
select 1, 3
union
select 2, 3
union
select 2, 4
union
select 2, 5
union
select null, 1

select num/den as 'calc' from @myTable
--where calc is not null
order by calc
```

Comment: Nevermind, found the reason: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31808423/cannot-use-alias-name-in-where-clause-but-can-in-order-by

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in [Cannot use Alias name in WHERE clause but can in ORDER BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31808423/cannot-use-alias-name-in-where-clause-but-can-in-order-by), it's due to the natural query processing order:

1. `FROM`
2. `ON`
3. `OUTER`
4. `WHERE`
5. `GROUP BY`
6. `CUBE` | `ROLLUP`
7. `HAVING`
8. `SELECT`
9. `DISTINCT`
10. `ORDER BY`
11. `TOP`